# Typescript doesn't bold the text when call it in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

bold function doesn't work in Typescript

Hello, so I'm working on Angular project and
I have a function in a typescript file that bold a specific part

```
      formatText() {

      ...........
      

      new_text = part1 +  word.bold()  + part2;

      return new_text;

  }
```

then I called I returned in an HTML file

```
                <div *ngFor="let sentence of sentences">
                <li>
                    {{formatText()}}
                </li>
               </div>
```

However what I get is the tags instead of bolding the word like this:

```
A young college teacher <b>leaves</b> China for the United States in search of a better future.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try surround **formatText()** with `<p>` tag in your HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let sentence of sentences">
      <li>
            <p>{{formatText()}}<p>
      </li>
</div>
```

Hope this would help

Minor suggest:
`<li>` tag should be inside `<ul>` tag

Comment: didn't work....

Comment: @nothanks I see the problem, sorry for my rush answer. 
Yong Shun comment on your original post is the correct answer

Comment: Because of angular lifecycle so the code above is not usable. Angular *ngFor will occurs after html is rendered

Comment: [innerHTML] worked thank you